# Atlasboard: where to put common server-side JS code?

Tags: atlasboard

Where do I put common server-side JavaScript files used by most of my jobs? I do not want to get fancy and create a new Node module, I just need a place to put a couple of utility functions.

Answer (score 0):

A Node module is the only way that works I could find. I created a .js file (for instance `utils.js`) in the package folder where `jobs/` and `widgets/` are, and put all my common code for export:

```
module.export = {
  commonFunction: function () { ... },
   :
};
```

In my jobs, I import the common code I need with:

```
var utils = require('../../utils.js');
```

and use the exported properties offered by `utils`.